# override type=password for input format

Tags: html, input

this is my login widget. as you can see the username and password fields have different textboxes. i want them to only have the textbox which the "username" field has. problem is that the only thing that differs them is the input type. and i want the password field to not show the password. which the username field will.

so how do i solve this?

the code is this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div class="widget">
    <h3 class="widgettitle">Honestreviews.se</h3>
    <div class="textwidget">
        <form action="../login-exec.php" method="post">
        <ul id="login">
            <li>
                Username:<br>
                <input name="login" type="text" id="login" />
            </li>
            <li>
                Password:<br>
                <input name="password" type="password" id="password" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in">
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="register.php">Register</a>
            </li>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="widget_divide"></div>
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8iUh7K8.png]

Comment: can you post the css?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D87VeC6T <- put it there since its so large

Comment: sadly, this didnt fix it. its still the old field

Comment: ive updated the code in the main post. do you think anything of that interferes?

Comment: hmm, i tried removing the entire css and just write "hi" in it. and the site still didnt update. i wonder why. that might be the problem

Comment: im using it on a webserver. and ive never had any issues before. and i let the server update for ~10 minutes and it still didnt update. also. i noticed that you removed like 200 lines of the css. is that really necesary? now i need to find the root cause of why the page doesnt update with the css

Comment: I did not notice that I removed 200 lines of code.. where is your css linked to your html?

Comment: first it was in the header. then i added it to the sidebar so i just could get it to work. i use this line of code for the css: http://pastebin.com/8KhK0SE3 its not wrong right?

Comment: could you upload your full project with http://ge.tt/ and paste the link here?

Comment: im not comfortable to include my passwords and i cant really access everything so ill just give you the sidebar itself, the index page which calls it and the style.css. index: http://pastebin.com/0wXNiYAA style.css: http://pastebin.com/vnEH2xDK sidebar_stretch: http://pastebin.com/jnCtyqSQ. you cant get anything to view. but all the sidebars will appear where they should

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />` should be in your header.php

Comment: $letsjak i dont know how, but somehow it solved itself now. i wish to give you a huge thanks for your extensive help!

Comment: I do not know what the path is to your css. Maybe "../css/style.css" is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your CSS. Most likely you're only targeting `input` elements whose `type` is "text" (although you may also be only targeting a `name` or `id` equal to "login"):

```css
input[type="text"] {
    ...
}
```

You can rectify this by including `input` elements with a `type` of "password":

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
    ...
}
```

**Update:** Based on the [code you've provided](http://pastebin.com/D87VeC6T) your selector will need to be changed at line 1166. You'll also need to change your `:focus` selector at line 1189:

```css
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, textarea:focus {
    ...
}
```

---

As a side note, semantically your code appears to be invalid. Your form elements are wrapped in `li` elements. What exactly is this a list of?

Comment: ive bought the css because i really and truely hate fighting with the css. and the code i provided isnt the whole. ill include it. check main post again

Comment: @Henk your HTML is missing the closing `</form>` and `</ul>` tags. The semantics issue still stands though, as the `ul` element is designed to represent lists (of data), not form elements.

Comment: THANK you for this. the code is fixed thanks to your answer. i love kind people who help me with my hate for css!